# Generate XML with attributes within the tags in c#

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite

I have following XML structure.

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d>54</d>
      <e>US</e>
      <f>Canada</f>          
      <g>
        <h>
          <i1>39</i1>              
          <i2>Belgium</i2>
          <i3>Russia</i3>
        </h>
        <h>
          <i1>43</i1>              
          <i2>Fran</i2>
          <i3>Ger</i3>
        </h>
      </g>
    </c>
    <c>
      <d>5</d>
      <e>US</e>
      <f>Can</f>          
      <g>
        <h>
          <i1>29</i1>              
          <i2>Brit</i2>
          <i3>Ice</i3>
        </h>
        <h>
          <i1>95</i1>              
          <i2>Russia</i2>
          <i3>Nero</i3>
        </h>
        <h>
          <i1>4323</i1>              
          <i2>Polska</i2>
          <i3>503</i3>
        </h>
      </g>
    </c>         
  </b>
  <b2>
    <c2>
      <d2>551</d2>
      <d3>Indo</d3>
      <e2>
        <f2>
          <g2>Irnna</g2>
          <g3>Mehak</g3>
          <g4>Vodka</g4>              
          <h2>
            <i2>
              <j1>44</j1>                  
              <j6>Germ0</j6>                  
            </i2>
            <i21>Finish</i21>
        </f2>    
      </e2>  
      <f3>544</f3>
      <g3>fur</g3>
      <h3>denmark</h3>
     <k1>lur</k1>
     <k2>Bern</k2>
     <k3>Zurick</k3>
     <k4>Italy</k4>
    </c2>
  </b2>
 <b3>35</b3>
 <b4>ferha</b4>
 <b5>english</b5>
 <b6>334</b6>
</a>
```

I need to convert it like following-

```
<a>
      <b>
        <c d="54"; e="US"; f="Canada">        
         <g>
            <h i1="39"; i2 = "Belgium"; i3 ="Russia">               
            <h i1="393"; i2 = "Fran"; i3 ="Ger">                
         </g>
        </c>
        <c>
       .
       .
     .
    .
```

that means putting all the attributes within the tags. i used the following c# codes-

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("my.xml");
                var xNode =
                    new XElement("a",
                        from name in xDoc.Root.Elements()
                        select new XElement(name.Name,
                            from names in name.Elements()
                            select new XElement(names.Name,
                                from namesElement in names.Elements()
                                where namesElement.Name.LocalName != "g"
                                select new XAttribute(namesElement.Name.LocalName, (string)namesElement),
                                new XElement("g",
                                    from Parts in names.Element("g").Elements()
                                    select new XElement(Parts.Name,
                                        from routeElement in Parts.Elements()
                                        select new XAttribute(routeElement.Name.LocalName, (string)routeElement))))));
```

But, I am getting errors. Could you please give me any hints or correction what was wrong in my codes ? actually, it works until  (first half). when the structure changes in the second half, it shows error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", "Duplicate attribute.". could you please tell me whether my approach is correct or not ? is there any problem in the logical structure ?

Comment: I'm thinking something like this would be better handled through XSLT.

Comment: could you please give me some sample which will suit my structure ?

Comment: Unfortunately probably not any quicker than the amount of time it would take you to figure it out.  10 years ago I could do fairly complex XSLT on a napkin with a pen, but I haven't used it since then. :/

Comment: i am trying to figure out, but please help me if you have any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample input XML document is missing the closing tag for the h2 element.  Also, the values in the input XML document don't match the values in your expected output XML.  That being said, I used your sample input (I added the missing h2 closing tag) and ran it through the following code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("my.xml");
XElement[] elements = xDoc.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text).Select(n => n.Parent).ToArray();

foreach (XElement element in elements)
{
    element.Parent.SetAttributeValue(element.Name, element.Value);
    element.Remove();
}
```

And the resulting output was this:

```
<a b3="35" b4="ferha" b5="english" b6="334">
  <b>
    <c d="54" e="US" f="Canada">
      <g>
        <h i1="39" i2="Belgium" i3="Russia" />
        <h i1="43" i2="Fran" i3="Ger" />
      </g>
    </c>
    <c d="5" e="US" f="Can">
      <g>
        <h i1="29" i2="Brit" i3="Ice" />
        <h i1="95" i2="Russia" i3="Nero" />
        <h i1="4323" i2="Polska" i3="503" />
      </g>
    </c>
  </b>
  <b2>
    <c2 d2="551" d3="Indo" f3="544" g3="fur" h3="denmark" k1="lur" k2="Bern" k3="Zurick" k4="Italy">
      <e2>
        <f2 g2="Irnna" g3="Mehak" g4="Vodka">
          <h2 i21="Finish">
            <i2 j1="44" j6="Germ0" />
          </h2>
        </f2>
      </e2>
    </c2>
  </b2>
</a>
```

Which seems like what you were looking for but if not maybe the code can point you in the right direction.

I've used the LINQ method syntax instead of the query syntax that you were using, but I don't think that part is important.  However I noticed that you were looking for specific elements, such as "a" or "g", and I wanted to see if this could be done in a more general way.

I too ran into null reference exceptions as I was writing this.  For example I originally had the `elements` variable as an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, but then later I would remove an element from its parent in the `foreach`, and on the next iteration there would be some LINQ deferred execution so it would go back to `DescendantNodes()` but it wouldn't work right with the element removed and I'd see the null reference exception.  So instead of changing things out from under LINQ, I `ToArray()` the collection so that all that execution happens right away, and I work with the array instead.  I mention all this because maybe that sort of thing was happening for you too.

Comment: anyway, is it possible to convert this xml format to database ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Imha You're welcome. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking when you say "is it possible to convert this xml format to database", which could mean one of any number of things, though I'm guessing that the answer is "yes". I would suggest asking this in a new question, with sufficient detail on what you are trying to do and of course including what you've already tried and exactly what problems you ran into. That way we're all on the same page and we can work together toward a solution.